# Pandas.DataFrame.str.replace function replaces floats to NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame, suppose:
`df = pd.DataFrame({'Column name':['0,5',600,700]})`

I need to remove `,`. The code is:
`df_mod = df.stack().str.replace(',','').unstack()`

As a result I get: `[05, NaN, NaN]`

Do you have any ideas why my expression replaces numbers with NaN and how to avoid it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have mixed dtypes so I think that the replace is causing the dtype to be upconverted to float

Comment: Really weird, because type of the whole column is object, and pd should treat all values like strings

Answer (score 21):

Those numbers are treated as numeric values, which don't have `str.replace` methods, you can convert the column to string, remove the comma, and then convert the data type back:

```
df['Column name'].astype(str).str.replace(",", "").astype(int)

#0      5
#1    600
#2    700
#Name: Column name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: thats wierd and inconsistent behaviour from pandas , no error no warning

Comment: This solution has some problems.

1. If the column contains mixed numbers and str, the last astype will fail.
2. I think astype(int) will fail if there are NaNs present. switch it to astype(float)?
3. If you skip the last astype, then NaN will be kept as strings

Answer (score 6):

As identified by @Psidom, you get `NaN` because `int`s don't have a `replace` method.  You can run it as is and fill in those `Nan` values with the original column

```
c = 'Column name'
df[c].str.replace(',', '').fillna(df[c])

0     05
1    600
2    700
Name: Column name, dtype: object
```

This preserves all the `dtypes`

Comment: I have a df['xxx'].str.replace('.0', '') seems to truncate everything but the last two of the string.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5):

I have an alternate answer, just for fun:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(',','') if type(x) is str else x)
```

This would check if every value for str type, then .replace for any str.

Comment: Tryed to use this variant, it seems it does nothing ) we need to run the iteration for x in some way

Comment: It works fine the the sample df in your post. Is your df somehow different?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, it works perfect. By some reason it takes too much time executing in debugging mode in PyCharm - I decided it doesn't work at all )

Comment: I've tried timing it for your sample df: 1000 loops, best of 3: 517 µs per loop. You shouldn't be facing much performance issue with this code.. ):

Comment: Yeah, in running mode it executes pretty fast. I'll use it