# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when using regex on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of part orders that I'm trying to standardize to allow for better analysis of the data. The dataframe has been compiled from a variety of CSV and XLSX files using the codes below

```
    source_data = pd.read_excel(filename,sheet_name,skiprows=HeaderRow-1,dtype=object)
    source_data = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=HeaderRow-1,dtype=object)
```

They are being read in as objects because the variety of different files come from different companies that have their own unique ways of labeling specific fields and most of the fields need to be strings anyways (Part Numbers, ID numbers, etc. that could be misrepresented if brought in as int/float.

On top of that, some of the companies' data feature oddball formatting for the price which throws in spaces randomly into the PRICE field (in addition to $ and ,).

This causes my data to look like the following

```
    P/N         DESCRIPTION     PRICE
    654A321     Item 1          $1 ,330
    783B257     Desc, Item 2    $55
    897653      part 4          $2 3,589
    789A234     Widget          5132.00
```

I've been trying to remove the [$, ] characters by using code like any of the following:

```
    data.loc[value,'PRICE'] = re.sub(r"[^0-9]+","",data['PRICE'][value])

    data.loc[value,'PRICE'] = re.sub('\$','',data['PRICE'][value])
    data.loc[value,'PRICE'] = re.sub(' ','',['PRICE'][value])
    data.loc[value,'PRICE'] = re.sub(',','',['PRICE'][value])
```

The set of 3 were inside of a for loop (for value in range(len(data)):).

However, no matter what I seem to try, I receive 
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I have checked the dtype of the column and it states that data['PRICE'] is of type object so I'm struggling to see what the problem is.

The end goal would be to have the table formatted like

```
    P/N         DESCRIPTION     PRICE
    654A321     Item 1          1330
    783B257     Desc, Item 2    55
    897653      part 4          23589
    789A234     Widget          5132.00
```

Can somebody tell me what is broken about my regex on re.sub and how to fix it?

Thanks (and apologies for the long-winded question).

Comment: Your passing g it a `Series` object, which is not a `str` norba `bytes` object. `re.sub` doesn't care about the `dtype` of your pandas object, it cares about the `type` of your *Python object*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use str.replace to replace whitespace(\s+), comma(,) and $(\$)

```
df['PRICE'] = df['PRICE'].str.replace('\s+|,|\$', '')
```

You get

```
    P/N     DESCRIPTION     PRICE
0   654A321 Item 1          1330
1   783B257 Desc, Item 2    55
2   897653  part 4          23589
```

Comment: An unknown side-effect is that this caused entries that already had the intended PRICE format to become nan. I assume that this happened because the values somehow weren't strings but floats.

I would think that this means I need to select only the rows which contain one of these characters, but how would I do that with .loc if re.sub reads the dtype of the column and not the individual row?

Comment: I found a solution to the follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187436/pandas-dataframe-str-replace-function-replaces-floats-to-nan

In short, I had to add .astype(str) before the .str function so it ended up as
        df['PRICE'] = df['PRICE'].astype(str).str.replace('\s+|,|\$','')

Comment: Sorry I missed both the messages, blame it on the weekend:) I assumed the column to be string seeing the $ sign, but glad that you worked it out. All the best