# Convert and replace a string value in a pandas df with its float type

Tags: pandas

I have a value in pandas df which is accidentally put as a string as follows:

```
df.iloc[5329]['values']
'72,5'
```

I want to convert this value to float and replace it in the df. I have tried the following ways:

```
df.iloc[5329]['values'] = float(72.5)
```

also,

```
df.iloc[5329]['values'] = 72.5
```

and,

```
df.iloc[5329]['values'] = df.iloc[5329]['values'].replace(',', '.')
```

It runs successfully with a warning but when I check the df, its still stored as `'72,5'`.

The entire df at that index is as follows:

`df.iloc[5329]`

```
value        36.25
values       72,5
values1      72.5
currency     MYR
Receipt      Kuching, Malaysia
Delivery     Male, Maldives
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does this solves your Problem??  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187436/pandas-dataframe-str-replace-function-replaces-floats-to-nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iloc needs specific row, col positioning.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': np.random.choice(100, 3),
        'B': [15.2,'72,5',3.7]
    })

print(df)
df.info()
```

Output:

```
    A     B
0  84  15.2
1  92  72,5
2  56   3.7
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   A       3 non-null      int64 
 1   B       3 non-null      object
```

Update to value:

```
df.iloc[1,1] = 72.5
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
0   84  15.2
1   92  72.5
2   56  3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have recurring indexing (i.e. `[][]`) when doing assignment, since `df.iloc[5329]` will make a copy of data and further assignment will happen to the copy not original `df`. Instead just do:

```
df.iloc[5329, 'values'] = 72.5
```